# SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, dll

I'm not sure what assembly I need to add, as it is showing `SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView` is missing but I have added the assembly `System.Core` dll. However, it is still showing the error that I need to add some reference.

```
List<clsDownloadAttachments> objlst = new List<clsDownloadAttachments>();
objlst = (List<clsDownloadAttachments>)Session["datsetRsult"];
var result = objlst.Where(p => p.mmid.ToString().Contains(mmidpk)).Select(p =>p.Filenames.ToString());
var rst = (new System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView<string>(result)).Items[0];
```

Please advise, thanks

Comment: You are trying to use an internal framework class. If you want the first item from the result, then use `var rst = result.First();`.

Comment: wooo.!! it worked.. Thanks a lot.