# Quickwatch to C# code conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I had to find a value with the quickwatch and this is what I got out of it:

```
((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)(new System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView(GvAllCustomers.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Controls).Items[0])).Text
```

*GvAllCustomers is my gridview*

The problem is, when I add this to my code it shows errors.

```
string sC_Name = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)(new System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView(GvAllCustomers.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Controls).Items[0])).Text;
```

> Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Linq' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I get that `SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView` isn't in `System.Linq`. But what should I replace it with?

Comment: Didn´t a google-search help: this for example: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1076903/Getting-error-that-systemcore-enumerabledebugview or also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38073790/systemcore-enumerabledebugview-dll

Comment: Yeah I searched the whole internet but didn't find anything of use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not supposed to use internal framework classes, rather rely on the public api...

```
var textbox = grid.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Controls[0] as TextBox;
```

Comment: Thanks! that helped me!